# nginx: whitelist via mail on access

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, authentication

I'd like to expose several services to the internet using nginx as reverse proxy. For a maximum of security, I came up with the following procedure:

1. Access to service.foo.bar is blocked by default for all IPs outside my local network
2. To gain access, visit foo.bar and login with username and password
3. nginx sends me a mail and asks me whether the IP address from step 2 is allowed to access foo.bar and all subdomains. Ideally, I would have the option to allow access for x hours. After the x hours the permission is revoked.
4. Access to foo.bar and the subdomains is permitted for my IP
5. Go to service.foo.bar and proceed with the login to the exposed service

Is this (or a similar) procedure possible with nginx?

Comment: You're not asking NGINX to be a webserver but a full backend server at this stage. You might get away with writing a custom Lua module but really you should have proper authentication on the services you're hosting (which might send you mails if you're so inclined) rather than trying to push this to NGINX.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for extreme pain and suffering for anyone who attempts to use these services. If that's yourself, you'll tire of it after only a few attempts. Save yourself a lot of pain and don't bother. If that's other people, they will have such a strong negative reaction that you will probably make enemies for life.